# HTML tags replace multiline

Tags: c#, regex, bbcode

I'm working on a forum and needed a replace function for the different tags. But it seems when it searchs for the [qoute] tag, it only search the first line, but I want it to search the whole string, since its blockquote and have multipe lines.

```
////Block Quote
regExp = new Regex(@"\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]");
strTextToReplace = regExp.Replace(strTextToReplace, "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>");
```

How can I make it do that?

Comment: See this post for parsing HTML with Regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` does not match newline by default. Use [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make `.` matches any character (including newline).

```
regExp = new Regex(@"\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]", RegexOptions.Singleline);

OR

regExp = new Regex(@"(?s)\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]");
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `/`.